# Not naive timezone when querying django

Tags: django, sqlite, timezone

I have deleted all timezone-naive entries out of my Sqlite-DB. So now they remaining entries have a datefield like this:

2016-09-04 13:28:16+00

When I now run my query like this:

```
result = Feedentry.objects.filter(date_published__gt=timezone('Europe/Berlin').localize(datetime(2016, 8, 31, 17)))
```

First I receive no error, but as soon as I want to access the result (or len(result)) I receive the following error:

```
raise ValueError('Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)')
```

Any ideas how to solve it or what I did wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django always stores datetimes in UTC. And in SQLite it [doesn't store any timezone information at all](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#migration-guide):

> [Databases other than PostgreSQL] store datetimes without time zone information. If you switch from `USE_TZ = False` to `USE_TZ = True`, you must convert your data from local time to UTC – which isn’t deterministic if your local time has DST.

So first you need to go through your database and convert all the values to UTC; otherwise, Django will not interpret the values correctly.

As for your comparison, it is correct if you're using `pytz.timezone` and a naive `datetime`. But the error message implies that whatever `datetime` you're passing to `localize()` is already timezone-aware. To convert a timezone-aware `datetime` you need to use [`datetime.astimezone()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone), as noted in the [pytz documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. So am I correct if I use the code above for my postgresql-DB but for the test-Environment I Need to use the datetime.asttimezone()-function to have the datetime-field timesone naive? May I ask you to provide me with the code line as it should be from your Point of view? Thank you!!!

Comment: @Kev: To really track down the error you should add the full traceback to your question.

Comment: Thanks Kevin - it helped me a lot. I had now replaced the timezone from the columns in my Sqlite-DB and it worked asdesired (same for my Postgresql on my server)